# Weird lxml behavior

Tags: python, lxml

Consider the following snippet:

```
import lxml.html

html = '<div><br />Hello text</div>'
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
text = doc.xpath('//text()')[0]
print lxml.html.tostring(text.getparent())
#prints <br>Hello text
```

I was expecting to see `'<div><br />Hello text</div>'`, because `br` can't have nested text and is "self-closed" (I mean `/>`). How to make `lxml` handle it right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTML doesn't have self-closing tags. It is a xml thing.

```
import lxml.etree

html = '<div><br />Hello text</div>'
doc = lxml.etree.fromstring(html)
text = doc.xpath('//text()')[0]
print lxml.etree.tostring(text.getparent())
```

prints

```
<br/>Hello text
```

Note that the text is not inside the tag. `lxml` has a "`tail`" concept.

```
>>> print text.text
None
>>> print text.tail
Hello text
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are dealing with valid XHTML you can use the etree instead of html.

```
import lxml.etree

html = '<div><br />Hello text</div>'
doc = lxml.etree.fromstring(html)
text = doc.xpath('//text()')[0]
print lxml.etree.tostring(text.getparent())
```

Fun thing, you can typically use this to convert HTML to XHTML:

```
import lxml.etree
import lxml.html

html = '<div><br>Hello text</div>'
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
text = doc.xpath('//text()')[0]
print lxml.etree.tostring(text.getparent())
```

Output: `"<br/>Hello text"`